# reference to temporary relation from qualification list

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1146

Consider an SQL query like this

```
SELECT Temp.rating, Temp.avgage
FROM (SELECT S.rating, AVG (S.age) AS avgage
FROM Sailors S 
GROUP BY S.rating) AS Temp
WHERE Temp.avgage = (SELECT MIN (Temp.avgage)
FROM Temp)
```

MySQL monitor gives this error:

> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'testDB.Temp' doesn't exist

What should I do to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Temp.rating, Temp.avgage 
FROM 
  ( SELECT S.rating, AVG(S.age) AS avgage
    FROM Sailors S 
    GROUP BY S.rating
  ) AS Temp
WHERE Temp.avgage = 
      ( SELECT MIN (Temp.avgage)
        FROM Temp                --- the error is here
      )
```

---

Depending on how you want to handle ties, you could just use:

```
SELECT Temp.rating, Temp.avgage 
FROM 
  ( SELECT S.rating, AVG(S.age) AS avgage
    FROM Sailors S 
    GROUP BY S.rating
  ) AS Temp
ORDER BY Temp.avgage 
LIMIT 1
```

or the simpler equivalent:

```
SELECT S.rating, AVG(S.age) AS avgage
FROM Sailors S 
GROUP BY S.rating
ORDER BY avgage 
LIMIT 1
```

---

or this one (that shows all tied results):

```
SELECT Temp.rating, Temp.avgage 
FROM 
  ( SELECT S.rating, AVG(S.age) AS avgage
    FROM Sailors S 
    GROUP BY S.rating
  ) AS Temp
WHERE Temp.avgage = 
      ( SELECT AVG(S.age) AS avgage
        FROM Sailors S 
        GROUP BY S.rating
        ORDER BY avgage 
        LIMIT 1              
      )
```

Comment: What if we have more than one such tuples?

Comment: Do you mean more than one ratings with same (minimum) average? Then use the last query.

Comment: OK. I got it. But, I think the usage of the aggregate operation(AVG) twice  is not nice and redundant. Instead, I used a view for AVG of the ages of the sailors, and dropped it after I'm done.

Comment: You can use a View (or a CTE in other DBMS, not available in MySQL), to have more elegant code. But the query that is run in the end, it's the same.